# Building and exporting hierarchical data from SQL query

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a requirement to query 9 years of data from a sql server database by fiscal years, then break the data out into excel files based on the following requirements

> Excel sheet - > Location
>
> Excel Tab - > Commodity
>
> Section - > Transport Method
>
> Row -> Customer Detail

The row will require the following information:

> Customer Name, FY14 Bushels, FY14 Ranking, FY 13 Bushels, FY 13
>   Ranking....etc

I have been able to build out my information to what I am calling the locationdetail level

```
Public Class LocationDetail

    Public Sub New(ByVal commodityid As String, ByVal commodityname As String, ByVal fiscalyear As String, ByVal shipmode As String, customerid As String, ByVal customername As String, ByVal quantityinlbs As Single, ByVal bushels As Single)

        Me.CommodityId = commodityid
        Me.CommodityName=commodityname
        Me.FiscalYear=fiscalyear
        Me.ShipMode=shipmode
        Me.CustomerId=customerid
        Me.CustomerName=customername
        Me.QuantityInLbs=quantityinlbs
        Me.Bushels=bushels

    End Sub


#Region " CommodityId "

    Private _commodityId As String
    Public Property CommodityId() As String
        Get
            Return _commodityId
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _commodityId = value
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region

#Region " CommodityName "

    Private _commodityName As String

    Public Property CommodityName() As String
        Get
            Return _commodityName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _commodityName = value
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region

#Region " CommodityCollection "

    Private _commodityCollection As ICollection(Of Commodity)

    Public Property CommodityCollection() As ICollection(Of Commodity)
        Get
            Return _commodityCollection
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ICollection(Of Commodity))
            _commodityCollection = value
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region

#Region " FiscalYear "

    Private _fiscalYear As String

    Public Property FiscalYear() As String
        Get
            Return _fiscalYear
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _fiscalYear = value
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region

#Region " ShipMode "

    Private _shipMode As String

    Public Property ShipMode() As String
        Get
            Return _shipMode
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _shipMode = value
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region

#Region " CustomerId "

    Private _customerId As String

    Public Property CustomerId() As String
        Get
            Return _customerId
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _customerId = value
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region

#Region " CustomerName "

    Private _customerName As String

    Public Property CustomerName() As String
        Get
            Return _customerName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _customerName = value
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region

#Region " QuantityInLbs "

    Private _quantityInLbs As Single

    Public Property QuantityInLbs() As Single
        Get
            Return _quantityInLbs
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Single)
            _quantityInLbs = value
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region

#Region " Bushels "

    Private _bushels As Single

    Public Property Bushels() As Single
        Get
            Return _bushels
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Single)
            _bushels = value
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region

#Region " Rank "

    Private _rank As Integer

    Public Property Rank() As Integer
        Get
            Return _rank
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _rank = value
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region



End Class
```

My current strategy is to build classes for each level of information needed with child collections of classes for the information needed below that level for example:

```
LocationDetail would change to an ICollection<Commodity>
Commodity would have an ICollection<ShipMode> 
ShipMode would have an ICollection<Customer> 
Customer would have an ICollection<FiscalYears>
```

Fiscal years would have the Fiscal Year, QuantityInLBS, Bushes, Rank

My thinking is that this would allow me to use the hierarchy to build my excel spreadsheet per collection as needed.

Before I begin this endeavor though, I need to know if there is a simpler way to do this? Are there better options for outputting the data in the format I need?

I have tagged this with SQL as well thinking that maybe there is a better way to do this straight from SQL.

***Additional information and clarifications***

I cannot use Stored Procedures, this is a vendors database and we have read-only access to the database. Since I am using Visual Studio 2008, I only have access to the initial version of EF which wasn't very robust. I am not having any issues with extracting the data that I need to present. I really am looking for information about the best way to move it from the format that I am retrieving into the format I need to present. It almost feels like I am trying to pivot the data, but not all at the same time. Please feel free to ask me any further clarifications as I realize this is not really a simple cut and dry question, but I think a lot of people have faced similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up creating a RankedListingClass that basically iterated through the data returned from the primary query, created a composite unique key based on several fields that guaranteed unique data and then ranked each unique item based on that key. Then I used that new class to generate my excel documents as needed.

Thanks goodness for linq, otherwise there would be a lot more foreach loops all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do some things like this in the past, and I have accomplished this with several different variations.

Stored Procedures (ado.net) with Classes (old way)

Entity Framework with Classes and Linq to SQL

Entity Framework with Classes and Stored Procedures

Nhibernate with Classes

For me, the easiest way by far has been using Entity Framework, Classes, and Linq To SQL.

Basically, EF mapping to your classes and then using Linq To SQL to switch around your data however you determine to be correct.  I would look into EF and Linq to SQL if you have the time.

Obviously, one other point that I will make is that when you get into the idea of hierarchical data, SSAS is really the place to work with data of this nature if you have some serious heirarchies going on.  (cubing)  I have done this previously too, but I wouldn't suggest this route as this takes tons and tons of time to get setup appropriately and would probably be overkill for your task.

Comment: hi, thanks for the response. I am not having any issues getting the data into my application. I am actually using a custom sql query and using a sqldatareader. It seems the most efficient way for what I am doing since its actually several tens of thousands of rows, even with the sql groupings that I am using. I will update my question to hopefully make my issue clearer.